# How to flush data in all tables of keyspace in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am currently writing tests in golang and I want to get rid of all the data of tables after finishing tests. I was wondering if it is possible to flush the data of all tables in cassandra.

FYI: I am using 3.11 version of Cassandra.

Comment: You can truncate table to remove all the data from table.

Comment: Yeah that's cool, And I know it but wat I want is to truncate multiple tables at once. My condition is that I write to more than one tables and I want to clear them at once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "flush" is ambiguous in this case.

In Cassandra, "flush" is an operation where data is "flushed" from memory and written to disk as SSTables. Flushing can happen automatically based on certain triggers or can be done manually with the `nodetool flush` command.

However based on your description, what you want is to "truncate" the contents of tables. You can do this using the following CQL command:

```
cqlsh> TRUNCATE ks_name.table_name
```

You will need to iterate over each table in the keyspace. For more info, see the [CQL `TRUNCATE` command](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlTruncate.html). Cheers!

Comment: Is there any ability to truncate multiple tables at once?

Comment: Actually the question was wrong, it was because I am coming from Django background and it was possible with django and PostgreSQL. Actually it is anyways better to truncate every single table

Comment: No, there isn't. You need to truncate one table at a time. Cheers!